# What is the name of text analysis where emotional tone of words is analyzed?

Tags: terminology, emotion, language

I'm interested in knowing what can be learned about people by analyzing the emotional content of the words they use in casual speech or writing. I've heard it being referred to as " ... analysis".

**What is the name of text analysis where the person's words are analyzed based on their emotional context?**

For example, statements like "life sucks" would be interpreted as negative, while "it's very helpful and I recommend it" as positive.

Comment: You are looking for the term "sentiment analysis", and I think it's answered sufficiently in the duplicate.  If not, the earlier question should give you a basis for narrowing down your inquiry further.

Comment: I agree with Chuck, your question is not exactly the same, but the answers for the previous one definitely answer your question.